# Do few/many vectors change how ML trains models?

Tags: c#, vector, ml.net

So, I'm using the VectorType attribute for ML.Net. The input data set I'm using is computed, and is super duper wide. We're talking over 10000 columns (still messing around this to see what makes sense, doing time series stuff). It appears that I can cram all those columns into one ginormous array and slap a [VectorType] on and call it a day... or can I?

My question is, what is the difference (if any) between the examples below in the eye of Microsoft's ML.Net? As in, does arranging the columns in some combination of vectors make any difference at all, or is that purely for ease of reading?

```
    public class InputData
    {
        [LoadColumn(0), ColumnName("Label")]
        public bool Label { get; set;}

        [LoadColumn(1, 10000), ColumnName("Features")]
        [VectorType(10000)]
        public float[] SomeValues { get; set;}
    }
```

and

```
    public class InputData
    {
        [LoadColumn(0), ColumnName("Label")]
        public bool Label { get; set;}

        [LoadColumn(1, 5000), ColumnName("Features1")]
        [VectorType(5000)]
        public float[] SomeValues1 { get; set;}

        [LoadColumn(5000, 10000), ColumnName("Features2")]
        [VectorType(5000)]
        public float[] SomeValues2 { get; set;}
    }
```

If it matters, I'm jamming these things into the AutoML API and letting it heat up my office for a good 8 hours.

Comment: Microsoft examples are very simple to make the concept easily understandable.  They are not meant for large applications.  When designing a database like you code I usually recommend starting with Excel to design the tables and columns before trying to write any code.  Each sheet of the workbook will be a table with the header rows being the columns of the database tables.  When designing a database there is a trade off between the number of tables, the amount of memory, and the use of primary keys.  Having 10000 columns is not a very good concept.

Comment: From what I understand, time series based things need to have each column be a point in time. Hence the width. But the question still stands - how does ML.Net treat vectors if they're giant or broken up into small ones?

Comment: Why do you care that every piece of data with the same time is in the same row of the database?  Why do you even care about time?  Our minds are not that complicated.  You have to design views that people can easily understand.  Once you start to put more than 5 different items into a chart that data get lost. I would start grouping the table(s) on the data type.  If you went to a grocery store and had each item a different aisle your store would be a mile long and 2 feet deep. Groceries only have a max of 20 aisle.  So design your database like a grocery store.

Comment: I think we're talking about different things? This isn't for a chart or a view. This is input data to train a machine learning model that uses time series data. Here is a python version that explains the same pattern I'm using: https://machinelearningmastery.com/basic-feature-engineering-time-series-data-python/

Comment: Then to answer our question the number of columns is just for the ease of reading.  Most programs do not have limits on number of columns except Excel 2003 which limited columns to 256.